# How to make a menu with icons spinning in a circle?

Tags: iphone, ios, uikit, caanimation

I am trying to create a menu for my app with a few icons in a circle. User should be able to spin this menu, making the icons change their positions around this circle path, but not rotating themselves. I read this earlier http://www.raywenderlich.com/9864/how-to-create-a-rotating-wheel-control-with-uikit so I can see how to follow the finger movement, but I need this menu to have inertial spin after the touch ends. I have 2 questions about how to do this.

First one, what's the best way to make animation with icons moving around in a circle? It should be slowing down until it stops and, if user moves his finger fast enough, should be able to do more than one full circle.

Second, how do I measure speed of finger movement at the end of it? I tried to use locationInView and previousLocationInView and just spin it by difference of angles between them multiplied by some constant. Problem is, when I keep my finger in one place for a while and take it up, I still get inertial movement of the circle and in this case I don't want it to move at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use a scroll view. Specifically you want a hidden scroll view where you attach the pan gesture recogniser from the scroll view to your custom menu view. Then you implement the delegate methods of the scroll view to redraw your menu. [This WWDC video has a good overview of the process.](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=223) The benefit of this approach is that you get true iOS style acceleration and deceleration for free. You don't need to worry about finger position or speed, only the content offset of the scroll view.

Unless you want to spin your finger round in a circle with the menu items. That's a different ball game...

In theory, the same approach as above can be used for spinning your finger in a circle. You would need to ensure that `directionalLockEnabled` was set to NO on the scroll view. The problem is that the calculations to determine the rotation of your menu view are a lot more complex. Probably you would want to be modal and check if the scroll view is `dragging` in the callbacks. If it is dragging you would use the touches on the pan gesture to find the exact finger location to set the rotation. You'd also want to maintain data on the instantaneous direction of finger movement so that when the touch is released... If it isn't dragging then you use the scroll view content offset to apply the deceleration effect on the rotation (using the scroll direction just before the touch was released to know how to use the content offset changes).

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I want to do.